# Unity: use UWP project in unity windows standalone application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, uwp

I am making a windows standalone application using unity.

I want to record video from PC webcam and save it locally. The only solution that I found is a UWP project that records video and saves it to PC.

I want to know if there is a way to use this UWP solution in my windows standalone application.

For C# projects (not UWP), I build it to dll and use it as dll in my application.
I need to find a way to do just like this with UWP project.

**Edit 1:**

I tried [Unity VideoCapture Example](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.VideoCapture.html) in both editor and build. In unity editor, the application runs without errors but it didn't enter to this function "VideoCapture.CreateAsync()", as they said it didn't work with the editor.

When I tried to build to windows standalone build, it gives me this error :
"Assets/Scripts/Controllers/Other/VideoCaptureExample.cs(4,26): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebCam' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR.WSA'. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: A reference to exactly which UWP Solution your looking at would be helpful...  You also said you built it as a dll, so why cant you use that dll to do it just like the UWP project?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1021138/Building-camera-app-with-library-in-Windows

I said I built other c# projects (not the UWP project) to dll. 
I don't know if UWP project can be build as dll

Comment: Alright, is there a reason you aren't using Unity's Video Capture capability?

Comment: It uses "UnityEngine.VR.WSA.WebCam" which is "UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WebCam" now. When running this function in editor it won't work (as they said in the description) and when trying to build it, it didn't build because of unreasonable error

Comment: I'll have to try that when I get home but this is the page I am looking at: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.VideoCapture.html

Comment: The same sample code that I have tried

Comment: can you update your question with that information?  The reference and the error you were receiving with the unity Video Capture.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the HoloToolkit / MRTK, you had best delete that folder and use the newer asset, or better yet, use the Master Branch which has more fixes in it.

Or you can try update your Unity to [2017.2](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/Manual/UpgradeGuide20172.html) and the sample works when testing on my machine.

Comment: I don't use this library. It seems that you didn't understand what I asked